# Multidimensional Array with PHP Soap Client

Tags: php, arrays, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to create a SOAP Client, but I need to send a multi-dimensional array (I think) as requested in the documentation, example below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.senior.com.br">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ser:ColaboradoresAdmitidos>
      <user>String</user>
      <password>String</password>
      <encryption>Integer</encryption>
      <parameters>
        <NumEmp>Integer</NumEmp>
        <AbrTipCol>String</AbrTipCol>
        <IniPer>DateTime</IniPer>
        <FimPer>DateTime</FimPer>
      </parameters>
    </ser:ColaboradoresAdmitidos>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I create a array like this:

```
$arguments = [
    'user' => 'xxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'encryption' => 0,
    'parameters' => array(
        'NumEmp' => 1, 
        'AbrTipCol' => '1', 
        'IniPer' => '01/01/2019', 
        'FimPer' => null
    ),
];

$client = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1));
dd($arguments, $client->__soapCall("colaboradoresAdmitidos", $arguments), $client->__getLastRequest());
```

However in the request, it seems that it does not accept the array, in fact I did some tests, and in addition to the first 3 parameters, but none enter the generated XML.

I already made the array in different ways, and changed the parameter value, but it always returns as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://services.senior.com.br">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
        <ns1:ColaboradoresAdmitidos>
            <user>xxxxxxx</user>
            <password>xxxxxxxxx</password>
            <encryption>0</encryption>
            <parameters/>
        </ns1:ColaboradoresAdmitidos>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Someone could help me, because the server understands that the parameter is missing, so I can't execute the query.

Comment: Can you use a loop instead sending multiple soap requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the internet, I discovered a lot of people with this problem and who couldn't solve it. I discovered the error.
This happens when the parameters do not match those registered in the WSDL. in my case: the documentation mentions the parameters with a capital letter, however, I had to use it with a small letter.

It seems that the parameter key has to be the same value as the one registered in wsdl.
ex:

```
$arguments = [
'user' => 'xxxxx',
'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
'encryption' => 0,
'parameters' => array(
    'numEmp' => 1, 
    'abrTipCol' => '1', 
    'iniPer' => '01/01/2019', 
    'fimPer' => null
)];
```